# Making a JavascriptInterface available across links inside a WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

I have a WebView, that is used like a browser to show and navigate through different pages of my website.

The WebView is loaded only once in the given Activity and then the other loads are by clicking on the links in the WebView.

**Here is what I want to do:**

I want to add a JavascriptInterface object which is available every time I load a new URL.

I tried adding it in onPageFinished but it does not work probably due to the fact that we need to reload the page once the JavascriptInterface is injected into the page.

**My Question:**

How can I ensure that every time a page is loaded into the WebView there will be an Object (containing a function with the @JavascriptInterface annotation) associated with it that I can use.

**Why am I doing this?**

Because I am designing a reusable API that can be used by applications loading multiple websites into the same WebView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to inject the object once per WebView instance, after you have inflated your layout (or have created a WebView manually), usually that happens in your activity's `onCreate` method. Then the injected object will be available in this WebView during all following page loads.

Trying to inject an object from `onPageFinished` isn't a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried some experiments and figured that out.